# How to add images to each product variation in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hey guys I have these 2 models,

```
class PrdtVariation(models.Model):
    prdt    = models.ForeignKey(Prdt)
    size    = models.CharField()
    color   = models.CharField()

class PrdtImage(models.Model):
    prdt        = models.ForeignKey(Prdt)
    prdt_vr     = models.ForeignKey(PrdtVariation)
    images      = models.FileField(upload_to=get_img_path)
```

I want to have images for each of the variation (not looping through every variations and adding the same images to all the variations) while creating the product, is this the correct model format for such a task?

Like the 1st image uploaded should be related to the first variation, likewise.

Can someone help with this?

I have created this serializer create fn, but it just loops through all the variations and add the same images to every variation.

```
variants = validated_data.pop('variants')
images  = self.context['request'].FILES.getlist('images')

for variant in variants:
    prdt_variation = # create the variants
    for img in images:
        PrdtImg.objects.create(prdt=prdt, prdt_vr=prdt_variation, images=img)
```

How to create a proper db table to and a function to accompolish such a task?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your form for the view?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support a `PrdtVariation` having a single image and that image can be shared between multiple `PrdtVariation`s you want your model structure to be:

```
class PrdtImage(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_img_path)


class PrdtVariation(models.Model):
    prdt    = models.ForeignKey(Prdt)
    size    = models.CharField()
    color   = models.CharField()
    image = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage)
```

If you want your image to be unique to only a single variant, but support multiple images per `PrdtVariation` you want your models to be:

```
class PrdtImage(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_img_path)
    product_variation = models.ForeignKey(PrdtVariation, related_name="images")


class PrdtVariation(models.Model):
    prdt    = models.ForeignKey(Prdt)
    size    = models.CharField()
    color   = models.CharField()
```

You then need a way to inform the view which image belongs to which variant. I would need to see your form for this. For example via the API:

```
{
    "variants": [
        {
            "prdt": "A Product",
            "size": "Large",
            "color": "Black",
            "images": [
                {"image": <some_image>},
                {"image": <some_image>}
            ]
        },
        {
            "prdt": "B Product",
            "size": "Medium",
            "color": "Red",
            "images": [
                {"image": <some_image>},
                {"image": <some_image>},
                {"image": <some_image>}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And then in your views:

```
variants = validated_data.pop('variants')

for variant in variants:
    prdt_variation = # create the variants
    for image in variant.images:
        product_image = PrdtImage.objects.create(
            image=image,
            product_variation=prdt_variation
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want the image to be unique to each specific variation. I don't have a form as of now, i am testing the api end point with postman. I don't use django forms.

Comment: You need to send the image/s as part of each variant via the API.

Comment: How do I do that? any example? If I loop through it, all variations will have all the images.

Comment: I'll update my answer so I can use codeblocks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it supports multiple images per variant, if don't you want that, change the `"images": [{"image": <some_image>}, ...]` to `"image": "<some_image>`

Comment: Thank you, it seems it depends on how we send it from the front-end, right? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's important, you need to inform your backend where the image belongs, through the above example, or with some ids or something. Otherwise the backend only know it has images and products but does not know their relation.